# Laravel 5.4. Как это можно реализовать?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравсвтуйте!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, как реализовать такую штуку(см. изображение).

Каждая фотография в личном кабинете пользователя имеет *3 checkbox*, при выборе которых справа должен появляться блок (своего рода корзина в интернет-магазинах) с тем что он выбрал с калькуляцией.

(Например, `3` фото - `A4`, `2` - `A3`, `5` - `A5`; и калькуляция, `A3` x `2` = `600` rub.).

В этом же блоке будет кнопка `"Отправить"`, которая должна передать инфу админу: какое фото и какого формата выбрал человек, общая сумма на которую пользователь "навыбирал".

Таблица в БД на данный момент только для личного кабинета и фотографий:

`id`, `id личного кабинета` и `путь к фотографии`.

Как я понимаю надо еще реализовать таблицу для форматов фотографий. Вопрос наверное больше относиться к реализации в frontend.

Comment: через js надо реализовать. А вопрос стоит закрыть он слишком общий и не однозначный

Comment: Пишите отметки все в локалсторедж например, если фотки на разных страницах, а при отправить отправляйте на сервер и сохраняйте в таблицу с результатами

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте роут по которому будет производится расчет данных  в зависимости от выбраного. На фронте обращайтесь к этому роуту тем же ajax по клику на checkbox ну и тем же ajax в случае успеха обрабатывайте / размещайте ответ на странице.